# classifying tagged images in Nvidiea Digit

Tags: deep-learning, nvidia-digits

I have a dataset of 18000+ images, they are tagged as 0,1 and 2. I need to train a model on Nvidiea digits. While making a dataset, it asks to provide subdirectories per category (i.e. it demands 3 folder : one for 0, one for 1 and one for 2) but the folder I have contains mixed images (they are tagged as o, 1 and 2).

Manually it is difficult to sort them.

Is there nay other way with which I can proceed.

Comment: Try the "Use Text Files" tab when creating your dataset. Hover over the question mark icons for details about each field.

Comment: Thank you :)

I did not find any Use text files tab on a Digit VM I used from AWS. Instead, I sorted them out using a python script.